# How to sort the digits of a number and get another number in Python?

Tags: python, int, typeerror, iterable, sorting

Beginner at Python and trying to code this program:

```
a = 0
number = int(input("Choose a four digit number: "))

while number != 6174:                                    #Kaprekar's constant 
   sorted(number) 
   sorted(number, reverse=True)

   large = "".join(sorted(number, reverse=True))
   small = "".join(sorted(number))
   number = (int(large) - int(small))
   a += 1
print(a + "iterations.")
```

I get the following error:

```
sorted(number)     
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

So how can I sort the digits of `number` and get another number?

Comment: What's the purpose of sorting a *single* number or are you trying to sort *its digits*?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: sorting the digits?

Comment: Yea, I want to rearrange the digits into a max-number and a min-number.

Comment: @user3556477 try this on you system: `reduce(lambda i, j: 10 * int(i) + int(j), sorted(str(number), reverse=True))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, putting `sorted` around an iterable doesn't change the iterable itself.  You need to do something like `a = sorted(a)`.

Now as for your example, you are trying to work with `number` as both an `int` and a `str`.  You need to convert between `str` and `int` when necessary here:

```
a=0
number = input("Choose a four digit number: ")

while number != "6174":
    large = "".join(sorted(number, reverse=True))
    small = "".join(sorted(number))
    number = str(int(large) - int(small))
    a+=1
print(a, "iterations.")
```

Finally, `a` is an `int`, so you can't do `int+str` in the last print statement.  Either put a comma like I have or do `print(str(a)+" iterations")`.

Answer (score 1):

For that, you can simply do:

```
number = input("Choose a four digit number: ")
```

Now your sorted will work

Thanks to @SimonT for the suggestion.

Comment: The `list()` is redundant.

Comment: You could do `number = input("Choose a four digit number: ")` and get the same result.